# CPI calculation

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I have calculated a graph with cache miss rate(mr) vs the size of cache(sc).  How can the CPI (cycle per instructions) be calculated for various cache sizes.
Assumptions are :

```
Given cache miss latency (say 10 ) , 
base CPI of 1 and 
33.33% of instructions as memory operations.
```

What I understand is that the CPI can be calculated using the following formula. Is the below method correct?

```
CPI = miss rate*(.3333)*10 + 1
```

for the `MISS RATE: 2.700978`
I got the following CPI

CPI: 1.090024

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking.  Your formula looks correct, but I don't know what the source code in your question is for.

Comment: @GabrielSouthern I am not asking anything related to source code. I had confusion regarding CPI calculation given the mentioned assumptions only. A simple explanation why the formula CPI = miss rate*(.3333)*10 + 1 is right or wrong would have helped.

Comment: If you aren't asking about the code why did you include it?  As for an explanation of why the formula is correct you wrote "What I understand is that the CPI can be calculated using the following formula."  Your question could be improved by explaining how you derived that formula and what you think is confusing about it.  Otherwise if you are just asking if the formula looks correct then the answer is yes.

Comment: I added some more details as a answer about calculation CPI.  Although I'm still not sure if I know exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate CPI when given a baseline CPI and statistics about cache hierarchy you can use the following formula:

```
Effective CPI = Baseline CPI + CPI of memory accesses
```

Your baseline CPI is 1 (given in the problem statement).  So you just need to find the CPI of the memory accesses.

If the memory access is a hit in the cache then we assume that the CPI is the same as the baseline CPI.  If it is a miss then it will be the miss latency.

So you have 33% of instructions that are memory accesses.  Of those the ones that are misses will take 10 cycles.  So putting all of this together you get:

```
CPI = miss rate*(.3333)*10 + 1
```

Which is what you have in your question.

As for the code you included and the "Answer" section I don't know what you are asking about there or what its purpose is.

Comment: I have changed my question as per your suggestion. I used the CPI formula by going through some links. But I was not sure exactly why it was correct. The explanation above is really very helpful

Comment: I'm glad my explanation helped.  I've seen a lot of people cut and paste homework questions without any information about what they've done to solve them.  When asking questions on stackoverflow it's good to try to make the question as clear as possible, and explain what you have done to try to find an answer.